# Can RAM be conceptually divided into 'stack' and 'heap memory'?

Tags: stack, heap-memory, ram, stack-memory

I have been reading up on how processes are implemented by computers, and found mention of stacks and heaps. This was pretty cool to me, since a lack of any kind of computer science background means that these things have been pretty esoteric to me.

My current understanding is that, on an extremely basic level, a process is represented in RAM as a fix-sized 'Stack' and associated variably-sized data structures that collectively are known as 'heap' space. Frames are added to the stack that may result in creating, editing or deleting data stored in heap space thereby changing a processes 'state').

So my question is, **can all RAM usage be categorized either as being part of a heap or part of a stack?**

What else could be stored in RAM that doesn't fall into either of these categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in extremely simple systems, especially old and not supporting multitasking, all user memory can be used by a combination of user code, user data, user heap data, user stack data. It's up to the programmer what to use memory for. The memory doesn't mind. But, naturally, there needs to be code and, in most cases, stack. Everything else is optional.

Comment: Even if a computer did support multitasking, I would have thought that all memory in RAM corresponded to some process or another, meaning that it must correspond to a stack plus heap? What else could be in RAM that doesn't fall under the heading of 'stack' or 'heap'?

Comment: With multitasking there are options. Either the address space is shared by multiple programs or every program has its own. In the former case there can be multiple heaps and stacks and portions of code within the same address space. In the latter case, there can't be (unless you explicitly create multiple). The physical memory (behind all the address spaces) may contain multiple stacks and heaps from multiple programs, unless switching requires completely saving a program's state onto a disk and loading of another in its place.

Comment: Like I said, the memory doesn't mind what's stored in it. Code or data (including stack or heap). It can be uninitialized (after power-up) and contain somewhat random content as well.

Comment: Thank you. Even if you were to store code, that would still require a process to retrieve code from somewhere and add that to memory... would that not count as heap space? What kind of random content does uninitialized memory contain and where does it come from?

Comment: A process is an abstraction. It's not a thing. Instructions are retrieved from memory and executed by the CPU, automatically, all the time (unless the CPU is in some kind of power saving mode or off). A heap is an abstraction too. You write your code to use N bytes of memory starting at address X. You subdivide and manage this space. That's all there is to the heap. The CPU or the memory don't know (nor they care) that you call this region of memory a heap and use in any special way. The stack is a similar abstraction. The CPU simply uses the memory the stack pointer register points to.

Comment: Random content is due to physical processes.